# Removing a column from a matrix

Tags: r, matrix

I'm a bit new to R and wanting to remove a column from a matrix by the name of that column. I know that `X[,2]` gives the second column and `X[,-2]`  gives every column except the second one. What I really want to know is if there's a similar command using column names. I've got a matrix and want to remove the "sales" column, but `X[,-"sales"]` doesn't seem to work for this. How should I do this? I would use the column number only I want to be able to  use it for other matrices later, which have different dimensions. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: `X[,!colnames(X) %in% 'Sales']`

Comment: Worked a treat, thank you!

Comment: maybe just `X[, colnames(X) != 'Sales']` ?

Comment: @Moody_Mudskipper the way suggested by @Sotos is better because it can easily be extended to remove multiple columns, such as `X[,!colnames(X) %in% c('Sales','other_col')]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

my favorite way:

```
# create data
df <- data.frame(x = runif(100),
                 y = runif(100),
                 remove_me = runif(100),
                 remove_me_too = runif(100))

# remove column
df <- df[,!names(df) %in% c("remove_me", "remove_me_too")]
```

so this dataframe:

```
> df
              x           y  remove_me remove_me_too
1   0.731124508 0.535219259 0.33209113   0.736142042
2   0.612017350 0.404128030 0.84923974   0.624543223
3   0.415403559 0.369818154 0.53817387   0.661263087
4   0.199780006 0.679946936 0.58782429   0.085624708
5   0.343304259 0.892128112 0.02827132   0.038203599
```

becomes this:

```
> df
              x           y
1   0.731124508 0.535219259
2   0.612017350 0.404128030
3   0.415403559 0.369818154
4   0.199780006 0.679946936
5   0.343304259 0.892128112
```

Answer (score 10):

I'm not sure why all the answers are solutions for data frames and not matrices.

Per @Sotos's and @Moody_Mudskipper's comments, here is an example with the builtin `state.x77` data matrix.

```r
dat <- head(state.x77)
dat
#>            Population Income Illiteracy Life Exp Murder HS Grad Frost   Area
#> Alabama          3615   3624        2.1    69.05   15.1    41.3    20  50708
#> Alaska            365   6315        1.5    69.31   11.3    66.7   152 566432
#> Arizona          2212   4530        1.8    70.55    7.8    58.1    15 113417
#> Arkansas         2110   3378        1.9    70.66   10.1    39.9    65  51945
#> California      21198   5114        1.1    71.71   10.3    62.6    20 156361
#> Colorado         2541   4884        0.7    72.06    6.8    63.9   166 103766

# for removing one column
dat[, colnames(dat) != "Area"]
#>            Population Income Illiteracy Life Exp Murder HS Grad Frost
#> Alabama          3615   3624        2.1    69.05   15.1    41.3    20
#> Alaska            365   6315        1.5    69.31   11.3    66.7   152
#> Arizona          2212   4530        1.8    70.55    7.8    58.1    15
#> Arkansas         2110   3378        1.9    70.66   10.1    39.9    65
#> California      21198   5114        1.1    71.71   10.3    62.6    20
#> Colorado         2541   4884        0.7    72.06    6.8    63.9   166

# for removing more than one column
dat[, !colnames(dat) %in% c("Area", "Life Exp")]
#>            Population Income Illiteracy Murder HS Grad Frost
#> Alabama          3615   3624        2.1   15.1    41.3    20
#> Alaska            365   6315        1.5   11.3    66.7   152
#> Arizona          2212   4530        1.8    7.8    58.1    15
#> Arkansas         2110   3378        1.9   10.1    39.9    65
#> California      21198   5114        1.1   10.3    62.6    20
#> Colorado         2541   4884        0.7    6.8    63.9   166

#be sure to use `colnames` and not `names`
names(state.x77)
#> NULL
```

<sup>Created on 2020-06-27 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

As always in R there are many potential solutions. You can use the package `dplyr` and `select()` to easily remove or select columns in a data frame.

```r
df <- data.frame(x = runif(100),
                 y = runif(100),
                 remove_me = runif(100),
                 remove_me_too = runif(100))

library(dplyr)
select(df, -remove_me, -remove_me_too) %>% head()
#>            x           y
#> 1 0.35113636 0.134590652
#> 2 0.72545356 0.165608839
#> 3 0.81000067 0.090696049
#> 4 0.29882204 0.004602398
#> 5 0.93492918 0.256870750
#> 6 0.03007377 0.395614901
```

You can read more about `dplyr` and its verbs [here.](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/dplyr/vignettes/dplyr.html)

Answer (score -1):

As a general case, if you remove so many columns that only one column remains, R will convert it to a numeric vector. You can prevent it by setting `drop = FALSE`.

```
(df <- data.frame(x = runif(6),
                  y = runif(6),
                  remove_me = runif(6),
                  remove_me_too = runif(6)))
#           x          y remove_me remove_me_too
# 1 0.4839869 0.18672217 0.0973506    0.72310641
# 2 0.2467426 0.37950878 0.2472324    0.80133920
# 3 0.4449471 0.58542547 0.8185943    0.57900456
# 4 0.9119014 0.12089776 0.2153147    0.05584816
# 5 0.4979701 0.04890334 0.7420666    0.44906667
# 6 0.3266374 0.37110822 0.6809380    0.29091746

df[, -c(3, 4)]
#           x          y
# 1 0.4839869 0.18672217
# 2 0.2467426 0.37950878
# 3 0.4449471 0.58542547
# 4 0.9119014 0.12089776
# 5 0.4979701 0.04890334
# 6 0.3266374 0.37110822

# Result is a numeric vector
df[, -c(2, 3, 4)]
# [1] 0.4839869 0.2467426 0.4449471 0.9119014 0.4979701 0.3266374

# Keep the matrix type
df[, -c(2, 3, 4), drop = FALSE]
#           x
# 1 0.4839869
# 2 0.2467426
# 3 0.4449471
# 4 0.9119014
# 5 0.4979701
# 6 0.3266374
```